# How can I add a background colour behind PNG, when image URL is pulled from my D3.js dataset?

Tags: d3.js

I am making a scatterplot, and pulling in an image fill for each circle on the plot. The problem is that the images are PNG's with transparent backgrounds. This means my overlapping circles show through each other:

Seen here - https://i.stack.imgur.com/bphon.png

I have tried setting a background colour with the CSS, but it seems to be completely overwritten by the .style("fill") in the JS. And I am looking to pull in 30ish images, so I don't want to have to save them all to be able to load the images with my CSS.

So, my question is, is there a way to put a white background behind my PNGs, while pulling those PNGs from URL's contained in my dataset?

Thanks for the help

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">

.axis path,
.axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: black;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.axis-text {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    background-color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.teamcircle {
    background-color: white;   
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<input type="button" id="playerbtn" value="See Player View">
<input type="button" id="teambtn" value="See Team View">
</div>

<div id="data">
    <div id="player-circles">
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

//Width and height
var margin = {top: 50, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40};
var w = 960 - margin.left - margin.right;
var h = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

//Create scale functions
var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([0, w]);

var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([h, 0]);

// var color = d3.scale.color();

// Define the Axis
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(xScale)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(yScale)
    .orient("left");

//Create SVG element
var svg = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", w + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", h + margin.top + margin.bottom)
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


//Load the TEAM data set
var teamdata = d3.tsv("team.tsv", function(error, teamdata) {
  if (error) throw error;

  teamdata.forEach(function(d) {
    d.entriesper60 = +d.entriesper60;
    d.carryinpercent = +d.carryinpercent;
  });

  xScale.domain(d3.extent(teamdata, function(d) { return d.carryinpercent; })).nice();
  yScale.domain(d3.extent(teamdata, function(d) { return d.entriesper60; })).nice();

//Create X axis
svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + h + ")")
      .call(xAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("class", "axis-text")
      .attr("x", w)
      .attr("y", -6)
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Carry-in %");

//Create Y axis
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis)
  .append("text")
    .attr("class", "axis-text")
    .attr("y", -20)
    .attr("z", 0)
    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text("Entries/60")

// DEFS & Pattern for images
svg.append("defs")
  .selectAll("pattern")
  .data(teamdata)
  .enter()
  .append("pattern")
  .attr('id', function(d, i) {
    return d.name;
  })
 // .attr('patternUnits', 'userSpaceOnUse')
  .attr('width', 20)
  .attr('height', 20)
  .append("image")
  .attr("xlink:href", function(d) {
    return d.image + d.name;
  })
  .attr('width', 20)
  .attr('height', 20)
  .attr("transform", "translate(2, 2)");

// Create TEAM Circles
svg.selectAll("circle")
  .data(teamdata)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("class", "teamcircle")
  .style("stroke", function(d) { return d.hex; })     
  .style("stroke-width", 2)
  .style("stroke-opacity", .8)
  .attr("r", 12)
  .attr("cx", function(d) { return xScale(d.carryinpercent); })
  .attr("cy", function(d) { return yScale(d.entriesper60); })
 .attr("fill", function(d) { return "url(#" + d.name + ")"; 
});
});
  
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wrap the circles in an outer circle with a fill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way I can think of is to create a group for every circle, and create a circle with a white background first.  Something like this:

```
var teamCircle = svg.selectAll("g.teamcircle")
  .data(teamdata)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "teamcircle")
  .transform(function(d){return "translate(" + xScale(d.carryinpercent) + "," +  yScale(d.entriesper60) + ")"});

teamCircle.append("circle")
.attr("fill", "white")
.attr("r", 12)

teamCircle.append("circle")
  .style("stroke", function(d) { return d.hex; })     
  .style("stroke-width", 2)
  .style("stroke-opacity", .8)
  .attr("r", 12)
 .attr("fill", function(d) { return "url(#" + d.name + ")";
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks for this. Instead of the .transform-translate I used the cy and cx values I had in there before, and applied it to each round of the teamCircle.append and it works.